# Vufoira - Videoplayhelper size Instance must have a constant size

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, vuforia

I am using vuforia for device base markers. Now according to my system all of its videos, placeholders and markers will be loaded dynamically. The issue i am facing currently is that `VideoPlayerHelper* videoPlayerHelper[4]` only take integer while i want to make it dynamic. So if anyone has idea about it or worked, kindly respond with a proper solution or suggestion. If i give it any variable like `VideoPlayerHelper* videoPlayerHelper[totalcount]` so it says `instance must have a constant size`.

Answer (score 0):

This question has nothing to do with Vuforia really - you cannot declare an array with dynamic size this way.

In Objective-C, the standard way to do this is to use the NSMutableArray class. This is a container that can hold any object. Example:

```
NSMutableArray* myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
[myArray addObject:[...];
```